# Using single helm chart for deployment of multiple services

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

**I am new to helm and kubernetes.**

My current requirement is to use setup multiple services using a common helm chart.

Here is the scenario.

1. I have a common docker image for all of the services
2. for each of the services there are different commands to run. **In total there are more than 40 services.**

   Example

> ```
> pipenv run python serviceA.py 
> pipenv run python serviceB.py 
> pipenv run python serviceC.py  
> and so on...
> ```

Current state of helm chart I have is

```
demo-helm
|- Chart.yaml
|- templates
   |- deployment.yaml
   |- _helpers.tpl
|- values
   |- values-serviceA.yaml
   |- values-serviceB.yaml
   |- values-serviceC.yaml
    and so on ...
```

Now, since I want to use the same helm chart and deploy multiple services. How should I do it?

I used following command `helm install demo-helm . -f values/values-serviceA.yaml -f values-serviceB.yaml` but it only does a deployment for values file provided at the end.

Here is my `deployment.yaml` file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "helm.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "helm.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "helm.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
    {{- with .Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
      labels:
        {{- include "helm.selectorLabels" . | nindent 8 }}
    spec:
      {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          command: {{- toYaml .Values.command |nindent 12}} 
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: secrets
              mountPath: "/usr/src/app/config.ini"
              subPath: config.ini
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      volumes:
        - name: secrets
          secret:
            secretName: sample-application
            defaultMode: 0400
```

**Update.**

Since my requirement has been updated to add all the values for services in a single file I am able to do it by following.

`deployment.yaml`

```
{{- range $service, $val := .Values.services }}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ $service }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .nameOverride }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .nameOverride }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .nameOverride }}
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: aws-ecr
      containers:
        - name: {{ $service }}
          image: "image-latest-v3"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: {{- toYaml .command |nindent 12}}
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .resources | nindent 12 }}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: secrets
              mountPath: "/usr/src/app/config.ini"
              subPath: config.ini
      volumes:
        - name: secrets
          secret:
            secretName: {{ .secrets }}
            defaultMode: 0400
{{- end }}
```

and `values.yaml`

```
services:
  #Services for region1
  serviceA-region1:
    nameOverride: "serviceA-region1"
    fullnameOverride: "serviceA-region1"
    command: ["bash", "-c", "python serviceAregion1.py"]
    secrets: vader-search-region2
    resources: {}
    replicaCount: 5

  #Services for region2
  serviceA-region2:
    nameOverride: "serviceA-region2"
    fullnameOverride: "serviceA-region2"
    command: ["bash", "-c", "python serviceAregion2.py"]
    secrets: vader-search-region2
    resources: {}
    replicaCount: 5
```

Now I want to know will the following configuration work with the changes I am posting below for both `values.yaml`

```
services:
  region:
  #Services for region1
    serviceA-region1:
      nameOverride: "serviceA-region1"
      fullnameOverride: "serviceA-region1"
      command: ["bash", "-c", "python serviceAregion1.py"]
      secrets: vader-search-region2
      resources: {}
      replicaCount: 5
   
  region:2
  #Services for region2
    serviceA-region2:
      nameOverride: "serviceA-region2"
      fullnameOverride: "serviceA-region2"
      command: ["bash", "-c", "python serviceAregion2.py"]
      secrets: vader-search-region2
      resources: {}
      replicaCount: 5
```

and `deployment.yaml`

```
{{- range $region, $val := .Values.services.region }}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ $region }}-{{ .nameOverride }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .nameOverride }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .nameOverride }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .nameOverride }}
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: aws-ecr
      containers:
        - name: {{ $region }}-{{ .nameOverride }}
          image: "image-latest-v3"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          command: {{- toYaml .command |nindent 12}}
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .resources | nindent 12 }}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: secrets
              mountPath: "/usr/src/app/config.ini"
              subPath: config.ini
      volumes:
        - name: secrets
          secret:
            secretName: {{ .secrets }}
            defaultMode: 0400
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Is using plain Helm a must? If not, I can write down an answer that uses [kluctl](https://kluctl.io) to implement your requirement. It could even be solved without using Helm at all (e.g. look at [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/x6klqf/comment/in7wslg/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) reddit answer as an example)

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend you try a helmfile-based approach. I prefer a 3-file approach.
What you'll need :

- helmfile-init.yaml: contains YAML instructions that you might need to use for creating and configuring namespaces etc.
- helmfile-backend.yaml: contains all the releases you need to deploy (service1, service2 ...)
- helmfile.yaml: paths to the above-mentioned (helmfile-init, helmfile-backend YAML files)
- a deployment spec file (app_name.json): a specification file that contains all the information regarding the release (release-name, namespace, helm chart version, application-version, etc.)

Helmfile has made my life a little bit breezy when deploying multiple applications. I will edit this answer with a couple of examples in a few minutes.

Meanwhile, you can refer to the official docs [here](https://helmfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or the [Blue Books](https://lyz-code.github.io/blue-book/devops/helmfile/) if you have Github access on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
helm install demo-helm . -f values/values-serviceA.yaml -f values-serviceB.yaml
```

When you did like this, serviceB values will override serviceA values. You need to run the command separately with different release name as follow :

```
helm install demo-helm-A . -f values/values-serviceA.yaml
helm install demo-helm-B . -f values/values-serviceB.yaml
```

Comment: Is there any other approach like I run everything in a loop since the only difference in each of my `values.yaml` file is the command section. So, I can include command in the same file like this
> command: 
>  - ["bash", "-c", "python serviceA.py"]
>  - ["bash", "-c", "python serviceB.py"]
>  - ["bash", "-c", "python serviceC.py"]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other approach like I run everything in a loop since the
> only difference in each of my values.yaml file is the command section.
> So, I can include command in the same file like this > command: > -
> ["bash", "-c", "python serviceA.py"] > - ["bash", "-c", "python
> serviceB.py"] > - ["bash", "-c", "python serviceC.py"] – whoami 20
> hours ago

Yes, you can write a fairly simple **bash** script which will run everything in a loop:

```
for i in {A..Z}; do sed "s/{{COMMAND}}/[\"bash\", \"-c\", \"python service$i.py\"]/g" values/values-service-template.yaml | helm install demo-helm-$i . -f - ; done
```

Instead of `command: ["bash", "-c", "python serviceAregion1.py"]` in your `values/values-service-template.yaml` file just put `command: {{COMMAND}}` as it will be substituted with the exact command with every iteration of the loop.

As to `{A..Z}` put there whatever you need in your case. It might be `{A..K}` if you only have services named from `A` to `K` or `{1..40}` if instead of letters you prefer numeric values.

The following `sed` command will substitute `{{COMMAND}}` fragment in your original `values/values-service-template.yaml` with the actual command e.g. `["bash", "-c", "python serviceA.py"]`, `["bash", "-c", "python serviceB.py"]` and so on.

```
sed "s/{{COMMAND}}/[\"bash\", \"-c\", \"python service$i.py\"]/g" values/values-service-template.yaml
```

Then it will be piped ( `|` symbol ) to:

```
helm install demo-helm-$i . -f -
```

where `demo-helm-$i` will be expanded e.g. to `demo-helm-A` but the key element here is `-` character which means: read from standard input instead of reading from file, which is normally expected after `-f` flag.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
But since my requirement has now changed a little, I have updated the question.