# Kubernetes multiple deployments using single template for CI/CD

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-deploy

I'm bit new to kubernetes, I know we can create multiple deployments using same template. I have already gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65024441/using-single-helm-chart-for-deployment-of-multiple-services). But my requirement is slight different. I have 30 deployment files wherein only two parameters that's deployment `name` and `python script1.py` keeps on updating for all deployments. Below are sample deployment files

`deployment1.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: deploy1    <-- Will be updated every time for all deployments
  name: deploy1     <-- Will be updated every time for all deployments
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: deploy1
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 2
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: deploy1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: nginx
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args:
          - -c
          - >-
              python script1.py     <-- Will be updated every time for all deployments
```

`deployment2.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: deploy2    <-- Will be updated every time for all deployments
  name: deploy2     <-- Will be updated every time for all deployments
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: deploy2
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 2
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: deploy2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: nginx
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args:
          - -c
          - >-
              python script2.py     <-- Will be updated every time for all deployments
```

I want to know how can I convert this into single template so that multiple deployments can be deployed into the cluster. Eventually I want to integrate this into cloud build as a part of my CI/CD.

Any help would be appreciated here.

**Update 1 :**

@Moritz Schmitz v. Hülst I have updated my code to include below files in my helm chart.

here is my `values.yaml`

```
deployments:
  - image: nginx
  - name: deploy1
    script: script1.py
  - name: deploy2
    script: script2.py
```

template/deployment.yaml

{{- range .Values.deployments }}

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: {{ .name }}
  name: {{ .name }}
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .name }}
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 2
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .name }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: {{ .image }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
{{- end }}
```

template/service.yaml

```
{{- range .Values.deployments }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ .name }}
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: {{ .name }}
{{- end }}
```

I get below error while running `helm install demo-nginx demo-hello/`,

> Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: unable to build kubernetes objects from
> release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: [unknown
> object type "nil" in Deployment.metadata.labels.app, unknown object
> type "nil" in Deployment.spec.selector.matchLabels.app, unknown object
> type "nil" in Deployment.spec.template.metadata.labels.app]

Comment: Does it help? https://serverfault.com/questions/993167/in-a-helm-template-how-can-i-use-items-in-1-list-to-iterate-over-another-list

Comment: @SanjayChoudhary I gone through this question too, I'm struggling to understand how can I loop over the deployment names and argument.

Comment: In the question you link to, there's a `range` loop that outputs a list of Deployment objects.  Can you adapt that approach?

Comment: @DavidMaze Approach mentioned in question I linked.. they are suggesting to create multiple `values.yaml` for each microservices which I want to avoid. Is there any better approach to tackle this situation ?

Comment: You could move the `range` loop into its own template, and `include` it multiple times; or you could create a `list` of the per-deployment values and then execute a `range` loop over that.

Comment: @DavidMaze would really appreciate if you could share few link I can refer.

Comment: Only three values change and the rest is all the same, do I get that right?

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst yes correct only only 3 values are getting updated for every deployments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deployment.yaml:

```
{{- range .Values.deployments }}
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: {{ .name }}
  name: {{ .name }}
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .name }}
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 2
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .name }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: nginx
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args:
          - -c
          - >-
              python {{ .script }}
{{- end }}
```

values.yaml:

```
deployments:
  - name: deploy1
    script: script1.py
  - name: deploy2
    script: script2.py
```

Comment: @Rahul, may I ask what you are trying to do with the script?

Comment: I will use this script to use it in cloudbuild for Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment to the Kubernetes Cluster.

Comment: I am asking about the function. Since you are using nginx and some python script.

Comment: I get this error while installing helm chart `Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: [unknown object type "nil" in Deployment.metadata.labels.app, unknown object type "nil" in Deployment.spec.selector.matchLabels.app, unknown object type "nil" in Deployment.spec.template.metadata.labels.app]
`

Comment: Does your deployment.yaml look exactly like mine? Just tested it again and it should work. Do you use other variables?

Comment: I have updated my question to include files I have used as per your suggestion. Let me know if anything is missing or anything is incorrect.

Comment: After removing the image variable from `values.yaml` it's working as expected.